# Angular service in Electron get data from Express error

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest, protocols, electron

I have an Angular 4 app nested in Electron, with express.js to fetch data from MongoDB. However I am now stuck at how to **"talk"** with express in http request.

In that angular service I have a method to get all player data

```
dataUrl: string = "/api/player/all";
getPlayers(): Observable<any> {
  return this.dataService.getCookedData(this.dataUrl,  this.finalizePlayerData); //the function pointing to data. It works in regular web browser.
}
```

Then in express.js, the listening API has been set up,

```
router.get('/all', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  player.find().then((result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

And now the app encounters an 404 error with

> zone.js:1980 GET file:///api/player/all net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I know the problem is at `file:///` that it should rather be like `http://` but I do not know the way to fix this. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the window is loaded from local file and not Express server:

```
browserWindow.loadUrl('file:///index.html')
```

it is expected that same base URL will be used for all XHR requests (including `Http`).

Whether API is remote or local server, its base URL should be hard-coded:

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3456';
...
http.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/player/all`)...
```

Comment: Wow that works! Guess I have to always give full path in services then.

Comment: Most likely. Even when running in browser, API can reside on different subdomain or whatever.